# Is there a way to reference Javascript multidimensional arrays safely?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Imagine the following situation:

```
var array = new Array ( [0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0] );
var x = 0; var y = 0;
if(array[y][x]) {
 // x and y can be any integer
 // code should execute only for array[1][2]
}
```

When `x` and `y` refer to an item in the array that exists, everything is fine. Otherwise, the script terminates. Obviously this is not the behaviour I want - is it possible to reference Javascript multidimensional arrays safely?

Comment: If you want to work with your array safely, you should check your array dimensions within if statement and then acess it.

Comment: Don't you mean that the code should only execute for `array[1][2]`?

Comment: @patrick: thanks, edited. You got the gist though, right? It's only a quick generalised example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the referenced property exists at each level of the array:

```
if(array[y] && array[y][x]) {
 // x and y can be any integer
 // code should execute only for array[2][1]
}
```

Comment: @Eric: then `array[y][x]` would return `undefined`, unless Number.prototype[x] exists :-p.  Really, that's down to the OP and unrelated to the question.

Comment: @EricMickelsen: Ach, yes.  I was sleeping.  And I just deleted my comment before seeing you’d replied to it.  :-\

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` keyword to check whether there is a y-th element of the array and whether that element has a x-th element as preliminary checks:

```
if (y in array && x in array[y] && array[y][x]) {...
```

Javascript arrays aren't so much multidimensional as they are compound/jagged.  You can also use `Array.length`, but that relies on the object being an array, which is part of what we're checking, so it complicates the check.

Comment: I know javascript arrays aren't truly multidimensional, but I tried to use language that would help others with my problem find this question more easily :)

Comment: @Chris Brown: I didn't mean to correct you, but rather to illustrate the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose than the other answers:

```
var array = [ [0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0] ];
var x = 0; var y = 0;
if(array.hasOwnProperty(y) && array[y].hasOwnProperty(x) && array[y][x] !== 0) {
    // x and y can be any integer
    // code should execute only for array[2][1]
}
```

...but this one is impervious to additions to `Array.prototype`.

Also, explicitly testing for equality with zero makes it more readable, IMHO. (Compensating for the reduced readability of the preceding conditions... :-P)